# Unity3D FB.GetDeepLinks parse results

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to get some working C# code of the results being parsed from FB.GetDeepLinks()

[Here's the Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.GetDeepLink)

Unfortunately their example code always returns -1.

The results I'm getting for the deeplink look like this:

```
{APPID}://authorize/#access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}&expires_in=3600&target_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fappcenter%2F{APPID}%3Frequest_ids%3D291251114389454%252C297829280380986%26ref%3Dnotif%26app_request_type%3Duser_to_user
```

Any help at all would be tremendously appreciated as this is just about my last roadblock from completing this project.

Thanks!

Edit: to be specific, I'm looking for the ability to extract the "request_ids" data from the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. was working for me a while back

```
void MyCallback(FBResult result)
{
    if (result != null) 
    {
        var response = DeserializeResponse(result.Text);

        foreach(object c in response)
        {
            var jsonObject = c as Dictionary<string, object>;
            string[] ids = jsonObject["id"].ToString().Split('_');
            FB.API (string.Format ("/{0}", ids[0]), Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, MyCallbackGet);
        }
    }
}

public List<object> DeserializeResponse (string response)
    {       
        var responseObject = Json.Deserialize (response) as Dictionary<string, object>;
        object scoresh;
        var scores = new List<object> ();
        if (responseObject.TryGetValue ("data", out scoresh)) 
        {
            scores = (List<object>)scoresh;
        }

        return scores;
    }
```